# Qt full screen window cannot get any keyboard events in MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, qt

Program environment:
OS:MacOS 11.0
Qt:5.4

I need to implement a full screen, But i don't want to use showFullScreen() function.
Because this experience is very poor, it will create a new desktop and have a sliding window process.
So I used the following code:

```
 QWidget* m_mainWindow = new QWidget();
 m_mainWindow->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::BypassWindowManagerHint |
                Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::NoDropShadowWindowHint |
                Qt::ToolTip);

m_mainWindow->resize(screen_width, screen_height);
m_mainWindow->show();
```

The full screen effect achieves the result I expect,But this window cannot get any keyboard events,Hope to solve this problem.

Comment: try `m_mainWindow->showFullScreen();` insted of `m_mainWindow->show();`

Comment: `Qt::ToolTip` may effect in a window / widget that excludes input by default. (At least, this would make sense to me.) According to [Qt::WindowType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum): `Qt::ToolTip = Qt::Popup | Qt::Sheet`. `Qt::Sheet` is obsolete but the doc. of `Qt::Popup` mentions [NSPanel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspanel). From here, I got lost as I'm no Mac OS/X expert...